# How to find the largest variable and print that variable name?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working on a small project where i have four variables which each could be lots of different values and i need a piece of code to determine the largest variable and print the variable name in a string.

```
list1 = [ICT,ENGLISH,LANGUAGES,DT]
print("The ICT department owed",ICT)
print("The English department owed",ENGLISH)
print("The Languages department owed",LANGUAGES)
print("The DT department owed",DT)
```

I have four variables with different values and i need to print out something like "The ICT department owed the most money with x amount" i've researched and found things like max() ,but i need the variable name not the amount.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 0):

Use Tuples in list

```
list1 = [("ICT",ICT),("ENGLISH",ENGLISH),("LANGUAGES",LANGUAGES),("DT",DT)]
max = list1[0]
for i in list1[1:]:
    if i[1] > max[1]:
        max = i

print("The %s department owed the most money with %d amount" % (i[0],i[1]) )
```